# SQL Server UNION ALL query

Tags: sql-server

I use a `UNION ALL` query and it outputs 2 rows for the same date. I want to output only 1 row like the second picture.

Do I have to use `IIF`, `CASE` or else command?

The date, time_in, time_out fields are output from other table (main_table) and then I use a left join with the following `UNION ALL` query.

```
   (select date, time_in, time_out,leave_start,leave_end,leave_type_id, leave_type_descr
   from   table1

   union all

   select date, time_in, time_out,null,null,leave_type_id, leave_type_descr
   from  table2)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you decide which `leave_type_id` takes precedence?

Comment: I want the leave_type_id with null start - null end (from table 2) take precedence if the date is the same.

Comment: Based on your picture though that is not true, because the `leave_start` and `leave_end` from the first picture override the `NULL`. You haven't explained the logic behind how to determine whether we pick 500 or 1. Using `GROUP BY` would get you all other columns except the last 2 - alternatively, scrap the `UNION` and `JOIN` them, then use a `CASE` statement to provide your custom logic.

Comment: I have 2 different tables with different kind of leave_types,that's why i use UNION ALL to get them all in one statement which later is left joined with another SELECT statement with all the dates exist the last 2 years.
Leave type1 is allday leave type while leavetype2 is a few hours leave type.

Comment: So, will table2 always take precedence no matter what value is in `leave_type_id`?

Comment: yes,there is only 1 situation when this happens,when the date is the same i want leavetype2 to be visible instead of type1.
I could also insert in table 1 the same leave types of table 2 so that they match.But i wouldn't want this because leave type2 is user created many times in a year as a sudden leave,whereas leave type 1 are fixed few hours leave.

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE( [ leave_type_id | leave_type_descr ] ) OVER (PARTITION BY date, time_in, time_out ORDER BY CASE leave_type_descr WHEN 'Leave type 2' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`

Comment: I will try both answers and let you know.Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the task correctly, then try something like

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( select date,  
                 time_in,  
                 time_out,  
                 leave_start,  
                 leave_end,  
                 leave_type_id,  
                 leave_type_descr
         from table1 ),
cte2 AS ( select date,  
                 time_in,  
                 time_out,  
                 null leave_start,  
                 null leave_end,  
                 leave_type_id,  
                 leave_type_descr
          from  table2 )
SELECT cte1.date, 
       cte1.time_in,  
       cte1.time_out,  
       cte1.leave_start,  
       cte1.leave_end,  
       COALESCE(cte2.leave_type_id, cte1.leave_type_id) leave_type_id,  
       COALESCE(cte2.leave_type_descr, cte1.leave_type_descr) leave_type_descr
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2
   ON cte1.date=cte2.date
  AND cte1.time_in=cte2.time_in
  AND cte1.time_out=cte2.time_out
```

Maybe FULL OUTER JOIN and COALESCE() for all output fields with arguments taken from both tables in proper order...

Comment: COALESCE was the keyword!!!And yes,i needed a FULL OUTER JOIN finally.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So some bits from table1 and some bits from table2, matching on lots of fields common to the both of them?

Does this get you what you need?

```
select t1.date 
,      t1.time_in 
,      t1.time_out 
,      t1.leave_start 
,      t1.leave_end
,      t2.leave_type_id 
,      t2.leave_type 
from       table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 
      on   t1.date        = t2.date 
      and  t1.time_in     = t2.time_in 
      and  t1.time_out    = t2.time_out 
      and  t1.leave_start = t2.leave_start 
      and  t1.leave_end   = t2.leave_end 
order by t1.date 
,        t1.time_in 
,        t1.time_out 
,        t1.leave_start 
,        t1.leave_end ;
```